# Pytest debugging in VSCode produces error message box "Invalid message"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, vscode-debugger

Using Visual Studio Code v1.41.0 and pytest==5.3.1. Test discovery and running works as expected.

However, when I attempt to debug any unit test I receive an error message box from Visual Studio Code with the text:

> "Invalid message: 'console' must be one of: ['internalConsole',
>   'integratedTerminal', 'externalTerminal']"

The message box has buttons labeled "Open launch.json' and 'Cancel'.

The "DEBUG AND RUN' configuration is set to "Debug Tests", and my launch.json file contains the following configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Debug Tests",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "test",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "justMyCode": true
}
```

That configuration was copied directly from the Visual Studio Code documentation page named [Testing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests), with the exception that "justMyCode" has been changed to "true".

As you can see in the above configuration, the "console" setting has one of the values that the error message suggests. This problem has been ongoing since I first installed and started using pytest, and I have grown increasingly frustrated with the work-arounds that I have been using to debug tests. However, I have not been able to find any documentation on the source of this error. Any hep or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're sure you are executing that configuration then please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Comment: I'm as sure as one can be... I even went so far as to eliminate all other configurations in launch.json. I'd be happy to open an issue... is the above description adequate?

Comment: Start with that, fill in the issue template the best you can, and we will work with you to figure it out.

Comment: I did... I'm actually working with someone from the team to try to get some logs for them. It turns out I'm an unwitting vict... er, participant in an A-B test for the ptvsd launcher. I'm a little overwhelmed with a deadline for work right now but I'm fully intending to be as helpful as I can be. So far it seems I'm mostly good at breaking things :)